# Read Binary FIle Lines From Memory

Tags: c#, memory, tcp, binary, client

I want to send a Binary File (Test.bin) from my Server Module to my Client Executeable, where it's stored in memory. On the Server-Side (C#) i create the .bin like this:

```
public static bool Write(string fileName, string[] write)
{
    try
    {
        using (BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            // each write-Array-Segment contains a 256 char string
            for (int i = 0; i < write.Length; i++)
                binWriter.Write(write[i] + "\n");
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then i send it to the Client like this:

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(Program.testFile /*Test.bin*/ );
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length);

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse((Array)bytes);

this.tcpClient.GetStream().Write(bytes, 0, 4);
this.tcpClient.GetStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

this.tcpClient.Close();
```

On the Client-Side (C++) i receive it and store it like this:

```
DWORD UpdateSize = 0;
NetDll_recv(XNCALLER_SYSAPP, Sock, (char*)&UpdateSize, 4, 0); // what's being first received

unsigned char* Update = new unsigned char[UpdateSize];
if (UpdateSize == 0 || !Network_Receive(Sock, Update, UpdateSize) /*Downloading file into "Update"*/ )
{
    Sleep(2000);
    Network_Disconnect(Sock);
    printf("Failed to download file.\n");
}
```

This all works well. Now the problem:

How can i read the lines, i wrote to the file on the Server-Side, into an Array on the Client-Side? I do not want to store the file on the Client-Device and use a Streamreader, i want to read it from memory!

Any help is greatly appreciated! (Providing some code would be the best probably)

Comment: Are you sure the binary data can't contain a newline character?

Comment: It does contain a new line character "\n"...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are serializing strings into your binary stream, I would to the following. For each string in your array:

- serialize the size of the string
- serialize the string
  (you don't need any separator).

In the C++ client, when you receive the stream:

- just read the size (numbers of byte to read depends on the integer size)
- when you have the size, you read the number of specified bytes so as so recontruct the string

Then, you continue reading the size, then the corresponding string until the end of the byte stream.

As requested a simple example:

```
string[] parts = new string[]
{
    "abcdefg",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Maecenas viverra turpis mauris, nec aliquet ex sodales in.",
    "Vivamus et quam felis. Vestibulum sit amet enim augue.",
    "Sed tincidunt felis nec elit facilisis sagittis.Morbi eleifend feugiat leo, non bibendum dolor faucibus sed."
};
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
// serialize each string as a couple of size/bytes array.
BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
foreach (var part in parts)
{
    var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(part);
    binWriter.Write(bytes.Length);
    binWriter.Write(bytes);
}

// read the bytes stream: first get the size of the bytes array, then read the bytes array and convert it back to a stream.
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
{
    int size = reader.ReadInt32();
    var bytes = reader.ReadBytes(size);
    var part = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
stream.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: could you maybe copy and modify my code? because i don't really understand what you mean :/

Comment: I have added a simple sample in C#.

Comment: Okay it works good now, could you just convert the reading part into C++ without using windows.h and other 3rd party libaries, because the c++ executeable is written for a device which only supports native c++. And thanks for your time and effort! :)

Comment: No sorry, I let you do the conversion since I haven't the time to do it myself. You have the generic binary serialization mechanism now, it should be simple to achieve :^)